# i'm facing problem to access value from database of lstpresentEmp and lstAbsentEmp , on Employee controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
namespace BarrownzAdmin.Controllers
{
    public class HRController : BaseController
    {
        EncryptionManager em = new EncryptionManager();
        static string empstaticid = "";
        static string rescanstaticid = "";
        // GET: HR
        public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            if (Session["HRuser"] != null)
            {
                ViewBag.ControllerVariable = 2;
                CandidateActivityIndex();
                GetScheduleIV();
                GetWeekIVSchedule();
                GetTodaysResume();
                GetWeekResume();
                GetEmpUnassignTask();
                BindPresentEmp();
                BindAbsentEmp();
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Access");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   [NonAction]
    public void BindPresentEmp()
    {
        Employee em = new Employee();
        MasterBusinesslayer hrLayer = new MasterBusinesslayer();
        List<Employee> _lstPresentEmp = hrLayer.GetFiveEmpLeave(em.BindPresentEmpl(), em);
        ViewBag.PresentEmp = _lstPresentEmp;
    }
    [NonAction]
    public void BindAbsentEmp()
    {
        Employee em = new Employee();
        MasterBusinesslayer hrLayer = new MasterBusinesslayer();
        List<Employee> _lstAbsentEmp = hrLayer.GetFiveEmpLeave(em.BindAbsentEmpl(), em);
        ViewBag.AbsentEmp = _lstAbsentEmp;
    }
```